# Rotate status bar icons like in the navigation bar when in landscape mode

Tags: screen, orientation

I want to do this to keep the status bar icons in the notch region when in landscape mode. I can see that showing time would be problematic but every other icon could just be rotated in place.

I wouldn't mind if the time was also rotated in place, e.g. For 10:23 you have

```
1 
0 
·· 
2 
3
```

It would free up more vertical screen space which is already scarce in landscape mode. Moreover, if your device has a notch then it's a much better use of the screen space than just blacking it out.

I was wondering if it's possible to do it in the user land at all or if only the OS can take these decisions and we'd have to wait for long for such a feature to appear, if it does at all. If it's upto the OS then where are such feature requests entertained?

I am using android P.

Comment: Considering it was up to Google to fix Android with the notch then it should also be up to them to rotate the icons when in landscape. Also, manufacturer and custom rom could do this. I didn't check and don't know if but believe they wouldn't give OS control like this to app devs since it should be same always and not need others to change it. Probably, its one of those things they didn't do or want done and everyone must live with it. If landscape works like this with the notch idk, but at least on my device the noti bar rotates to the side and display normally and apps can hide it. Best way.